# time complexity of binary tree to DLL conversion

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am looking at an algorithm to convert a binary tree to Doubly Link List (DLL).

```
1. If left subtree exists, process the left subtree
…..1.a) Recursively convert the left subtree to DLL.
…..1.b) Then find inorder predecessor of root in left subtree (inorder predecessor is rightmost node in left subtree).
…..1.c) Make inorder predecessor as previous of root and root as next of inorder predecessor.
2. If right subtree exists, process the right subtree (Below 3 steps are similar to left subtree).
…..2.a) Recursively convert the right subtree to DLL.
…..2.b) Then find inorder successor of root in right subtree (inorder successor is leftmost node in right subtree).
…..2.c) Make inorder successor as next of root and root as previous of inorder successor.
3. Find the leftmost node and return it (the leftmost node is always head of converted DLL).
```

What is that time complexity of this algorithm ?

Here is a link to the program 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-convert-a-given-binary-tree-to-doubly-linked-list/

Comment: go to left of the tree, then keep going right. It should take  O(h), h being height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we can see that all nodes are visited exactly once in the role of *root* of their descendants. All the work that is done for one such root is constant, except for the loops that are executed in steps *1.b* and *2.b* and except the work that is done for descendant nodes recursively.

We can say the algorithm runs in **O(n) + O(f(n))**, where **f** needs to be defined still, but the first term **O(n)** accounts for time spent for all nodes on all steps except those loops.

As my initial answer was wrong, I now go in some (probably too much) detail to get to the right answer:

In completely balanced trees, the number of loop iterations executed per (sub)root of a tree with **n** nodes corresponds to the depth **d(n)** of that tree. This **d(n)** corresponds to (for balanced trees): **log<sub>2</sub>(n+1)**. If we count the work for executing `left->right!=NULL` and `right->left!=NULL` as one unit of work (in [this code](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-convert-a-given-binary-tree-to-doubly-linked-list/)), then the number of executed units per node is **d(n)**.

If we accumulate this time from the recursion, we get a total number of work units per number of nodes **n**:

```
f(1) = 1
f(n) = 2.f((n-1)/2) + d(n)
```

In a table:

```
|  n | d(n)=log(n+1) | f(n) |
+----+---------------+------+
|  1 |       1       |   1  |
|  3 |       2       |   4  | 
|  7 |       3       |  11  |
| 15 |       4       |  26  |
| 31 |       5       |  57  |
| .. |      ..       |  ..  |
```

A value in the **f(n)** column corresponds to the double of the value above it plus the value besides it, according to the formula.

One can work out that **f(n) = 2<sup>d+1</sup>-d-2 = 2n-log(n+1)**, which in the above table means that the double of the first column, minus the second column, is the third.

In time complexity notation the constant terms can be taken out, constant factors can be set to 1 and the term that grows fastest for increasing *n* cancels out any other terms, so we finally get **O(n)**.

As we already had **O(n)** for the constant time per node, nothing changes. The time spent on getting the inorder predecessor/successor is not influencing the total time complexity.

The time complexity is therefore **O(n)**.

Comment: I can't get my head around the point where you reached log(logn) from logn. Can you explain or give me a pointer to some article.

Comment: No wonder you could not get your head around that: it was wrong. I have corrected my answer. Finally, the time complexity is a plain **O(n)**.

Comment: I have an another theory, f(n) = 2f(n-1) + log(n), so we have a summition, log(n) + log(n-1) .... log(1) = log(n!), and by Stirling's approximation, log(n!) = nlogn - n + O(logn). So complexity should be nlog(n). Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: That brings me to another error: the formula for f(n) should be relative to the recursive result, i.e. for `(n-1)/2`, not `n-1`. So although what you write is correct it it were `n-1`, the situation is actually different. Fixed that error. In what I had written I had in fact this `(n-1)/2` in mind, so the conclusion still stands: **O(n)**.

Comment: Could you give some feed-back whether this answered your question?

Comment: yes, it did solve my problem. but I had one doubt  how do i get f(n) = 2d+1-d-2 = 2n-log(n+1)

Comment: Well, that formula I got by a bit of guess-work, but once you have it, it is easy to prove by induction. [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536404/proof-by-induction-for-a-recursive-sequence-and-a-formula) is a similar formula and the proof by induction.